# Angular momentum using tensors. Identities in mixed products

Tags: angular-momentum, tensor-calculus

I was studying the angular momentum equation in the continuum case and I encountered this identity. I really don't find what properties are being used: $$\int_s -\vec{n}\cdot(\underline{\sigma}\times\vec{r})dS=\int_s -\vec{n}\cdot\underline{\sigma}\times\vec{r}dS = \int_s \vec{r}\times\vec{n}\cdot\underline{\sigma}dS$$ where $\vec{n}$ and $\vec{r}$ are first-order tensors (vectors) and $\underline{\sigma}$ is a second-order tensor.

Comment: what is a 2nd rank tensor cross-product with a vector? $\epsilon_{ijk}\sigma_{ij}r_k$ should be zero, since rank-2 tensors are symmetric.

Comment: @JEB https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1307835/cross-product-between-a-vector-and-a-2nd-order-tensor you can have a look here for example

Answer (score 1):

I finally found an answer. Basically, there is no order in the operation, thus one can see the dot product as a single object. The anticommutative property odds. Calling $\vec{n}\cdot\underline{\sigma}=\vec{a}$ then: $$ 
-\vec{a}\times\vec{r}=\vec{r}\times\vec{a}$$